# How would I create a palindrome checker without if statements

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a programme like this previous one I've made;

It simply gives a boolean true/false on if a string backwards is still spelt the same way.

I've created this using if statements, but would like too know if it is possible too create using only methods and loops, and if so how? I have looked for duplicates, and there are similar posts that achieve what I have below, but everything I find uses *if else statements*

Any help appreciated as always; thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
public class testingthingsv24 {

private static Scanner in;

public static void main(String args[])
{
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your String: ");
    String n=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Your String Was: "+n);
    StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer(n);
    StringBuffer str2=new StringBuffer(str.reverse());
    String s2=new String(str2);
    System.out.println("Reversed Is: "+str2);
    if(n.equals(s2))    
        System.out.println("ITS A PALINDROME");
    else
        System.out.println("ITS NOT A PALINDROME");
}
}
```

Output:

```
Please Enter Your String: 
dad
Your String Was: dad
Reversed Is: dad
ITS A PALINDROME
```

Comment: `System.out.println(n.equals(s2) ? "ITS A PALINDROME" : "ITS NOT A PALINDROME");`

Comment: @shmosel ternaries are basically just syntactic sugar for an if statement. But maybe that's what OP wants anyway.

Comment: @shmosel A ternary is basically an `if-statement` but its a cool thought - not sure what the OP wants though..

Comment: `String out = "ITS NOT A PALINDROME"; while (n.equals(s2)) { out = "ITS A PALINDROME"; break; } System.out.println(out);`

Comment: `try { assert n.equals(s2); System.out.println("ITS A PALINDROME"); } catch (AssertionError e) { System.out.println("ITS NOT A PALINDROME"); }`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codegolf.se].

Comment: Could put the answers in an array `string[] results = new string[]{"ITS A PALINDROME", "ITS NOT A PALINDROME"}`.  Then map to a result `System.out.println(results[0])`;

Comment: You could use a loop with `charAt`, but that's little more than disguising `if` statements really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would like too know if it is possible too create using only methods and loops, and if so how?

Sure.  The `if` statement is redundant in Java.  There are plenty of other conditionals in the language, and there are multiple ways that you could implement the semantics of an `if` statement (including an `else` clause, if desired) without actually using an `if` statement.

For example, you can always replace

```
if (condition) {
    // statements when true ...
} else {
    // statements when false ...
}
```

with

```
if_replacement: do {
    while (condition) {
        // statements when true ...
        break if_replacement;
    }
    // statements when false ...
} while (false);
```

Note that that has no association whatever with any particular problem, and that it uses only looping constructs.  A somewhat simpler form is possible if you don't need the analog of an `else` block.  In principle you could replace every `if` in any program with a construct of this form.

Answer (score 2):

To test a result, generally a conditional statement (`if`, ternary or `switch`) appears useful.
You have to avoid using conditional statements as these conditions are annoying by making your code not readable, brittle, error prone, etc..

To do that, you have to favor abstraction over sequential logic.

In your simple case, you could for example introduce a structure (key-value) that associate each `boolean` value to the `String` message.

```
Map<Boolean, String> messageByBoolean = new HashMap<>();
messageByBoolean.put(true, "ITS A PALINDROME");
messageByBoolean.put(false, "ITS NOT A PALINDROME");
...
System.out.println(messageByBoolean.get(n.equals(s2));
```

But does it make really sense ?
 It looks like an overhead as you have just two possibilities.
With 5 or 10 of them, it would make much sense.

Comment: I was thinking it was `Map<String, Boolean> ...`. Put the original String in first as key with a value of `false`, then put in the reverse String with a value of `true`. Then display the value with the key being the original string, where the value would have changed if the reverse is equal to the original string.

Comment: You cannot do it in this way as to get the `String`, you need to test the `n.equals(s2)` with a conditional statement. To not evaluate the `boolean` expression in your code, the `Map` needs to have as key what you don't want to test : the boolean value. So `Map<Boolean, String>` makes more sense.

Comment: I realise I wasn't very clear in my explanation. This is what I meant: https://www.ideone.com/ob8p8z So using the String to test as a key, and having the value be if it's a palindrome or not.

Comment: It doesn' t display the expected message and it cannot handle all cases. Why use a not adapted structure ?

Comment: It displayed the expected value for me. And it was an exercise of possibility that anything else. The question, as I saw it, was "Is this possible?". And I found my example to work as expected. I would not use it, though, as it's neither readable nor efficient.

Comment: Also, what cases can it not handle? I can't think of any that it wouldn't take into account.

Answer (score 0):

This can't really be achieved any more efficiently (as in using a `method` or `function`). The reason is that the `if-statement`:

```
if (n.equals(s2))    
    System.out.println("ITS A PALINDROME");
else
    System.out.println("ITS NOT A PALINDROME");
```

at the processor level would simply evaluate the `statement`: `n.equals(s2)` and then switch to the first `println` if `true` `else` go to the second `println`. If you think about this, there isn't really any optimisation that you can do as this condition will *always* have to be `evaluated` and *always* have to carry out the necessary task (`printing)`.

---

However, having said that this is the most optimised solution for this part of your code, you can make the `code` slightly shorted and less bulky without a big `if-else`.

And to do that, the best solution IMO would be `@shmosel's` with a `ternary` expression. This would replace this `if-else` block with a simple `line`:

```
System.out.println(n.equals(s2) ? "ITS A PALINDROME" : "ITS NOT A PALINDROME");
```

This works due to the general format of a `ternary` statement:

```
condition ? task if true : task if false
```

Comment: OP isn't asking about efficiency, but possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with recursion too

```
boolean isPalindrome (String s) {
    return s.length() < 2 ? true : s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length() - 1) && isPalindrome(s.substring(1,s.length() - 1));
}
```